# CSV Reader Does not Register Changes

Tags: java, csv, gradle, javafx, java-8

I am making an app where users can track the food they eat - a requirement of this is to have them able to add new foods to their portfolio.

To display the foods they have created to them, I am loading in a CSV file from my raw folder to be displayed in a TableView.

The loading of the file is achieved in the following method:

```
public static ArrayList<Meals> load(String fileName) {
    ArrayList<Meals> listings = new ArrayList<Meals>();
    try{

        URL url = MealLoader.class.getResource("/raw/"+fileName);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(url.toURI())));

        String [] line;
        //skip the first row (column headers)
        reader.readNext();
        while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            int key = convertInt(line[0]);
            String type = line[1];
            String name = line[2];
            double calories = convertDouble(line[3]);
            double carbs = convertDouble(line[4]);
            double protein = convertDouble(line[5]);
            double fat = convertDouble(line[6]);
            double saturates = convertDouble(line[7]);
            double sugar = convertDouble(line[8]);
            double fibre = convertDouble(line[9]);
            double salt = convertDouble(line[10]);
            double b1 = convertDouble(line[11]);
            double b2 = convertDouble(line[12]);
            double b3 = convertDouble(line[13]);
            double b6 = convertDouble(line[14]);
            double b9 = convertDouble(line[15]);
            double b12 = convertDouble(line[16]);
            double d = convertDouble(line[17]);
            double iron = convertDouble(line[18]);

            Meals listing = new Meals(key, type, name, calories, carbs, protein, fat, saturates, sugar, fibre, salt, b1, b2, b3, b6, b9, b12, d, iron);
            System.out.println("Created meal");
            listings.add(listing);
        }
    } catch(IOException | URISyntaxException e){
        System.out.println("Failure! Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Success! Number of loaded records: " + listings.size());
    return listings;
}
```

The user has the ability to create a new food.

When they do, the file "meals.csv" is successfully changed to have an additional new row.

This row is added immediately after the user clicks the "confirm" button, after inputting the name and nutritional information of the new food.

However, when you go back to the tableView, the food is not there, despite loading in all of the meals again, and the new record being present in the CSV file.

I have it print out how many meals are loaded in by the above 'load' method, and it is the same before and after the new record, **even though the CSV file has been updated.**

When you close and relaunch the app, the meal then appears.

The code is taken from the old version of this app that did not use Gradle or an MVC configuration, and was using Java 13 instead of Java 8 which I am now using - it worked perfectly before, and looking between the two versions, the only difference is within this load function, in the fact that it gets the .csv from the 'raw' folder.

File directory:

[image]

Old Version of the Code:

```
public static ArrayList<Meals> load(String fileName) {
        ArrayList<Meals> listings = new ArrayList<Meals>();
        try{
            URL url = MealLoader.class.getResource(fileName);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(url.toURI()).getAbsolutePath()));
            String [] line;
            //skip the first row (column headers)
            reader.readNext();
            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                int key = convertInt(line[0]);
```

(Continues on as before)

Build.gradle:

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html
 */

 buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }

     dependencies {
         classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.17'
     }
 }

 plugins {
     id 'java'
     id 'application'
     //id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'

 }

apply plugin:'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

 mainClassName = "src.main.java.MainMenu"

 jfxmobile {

 javafxportsVersion = '8.60.12'

 android {
 applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.ensemble'
  compileSdkVersion = '27'
  androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Luke/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk'

  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
 }

     ios {
         forceLinkClasses = ['ensemble.**.*']
     }
 }


repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
     url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
 }
 mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is found on compile classpath of this component and consumers.
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-junit:4.0.15-alpha'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
      compile "com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0"
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.jfxtras', name: 'jmetro', version: '8.6.5'

}

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

Is there something that I am missing that means there is a simple explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: where/how do you store the changed file? If in the raw folder, chances are that the version in the output path isn't updated. Anyway, same procedure as always: [mcve] please ;)

Comment: `getResource` is meant for embedded files deployed with your program. It is not the right thing for user editable files.

Comment: @Andy getAbsolutePath was removed to make the code clearer as I tested if it changed anything, and it didn't.

Comment: @Holger Thank-you. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's all to do with the way the file is retrieved.

Using:

```
URL url = MealLoader.class.getResource("/raw/"+fileName);
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(url.toURI())));
```

doesn't work, and must be replaced by an alternative such as:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("./src/main/resources/raw/"+fileName));
```

It is also advantageous as it is more readable.

However, why this is the case is a mystery to me, especially in the fact that 'getResource' worked for the first project, and not the second.